# Magento2 : I am seeing same block code i have added in CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

I am trying to insert phtml block in home page CMS in Magento 2. But I am seeing the same block code I have added in CMS backend in front end.

```
{{block type="template" template="page/test.phtml"}}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class to call **phtml** files

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}
```

use this code in cms page or static block.